# EfCore 3.1 CosmosDb Query Could not be translated

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.0

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet
    .GroupBy(
        source: e => new { 
            ExchangeName = e.ExchangeName, 
            TimeFrame = e.TimeFrame, 
            Symbol = e.Symbol
         }, 
        keySelector: e => e)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

```
var query = from stick in context.EmaExchangeEventSpecifications
     group stick by new { stick.ExchangeName, stick.TimeFrame, stick.Symbol } into g
     select new { g.Key.ExchangeName, g.Key.TimeFrame, g.Key.Symbol, Count = g.Count() };
var results = query.ToList();
```

What do I need to change to get this query to translate?  Or maybe this isn't supported on Cosmos?

Answer (score 2):

We now have a work item to enable this support. You can track from here.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1202

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way Group By clauses work in EF Core 3.x has changed significantly.  Many expressions that used to be supported are no longer supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: Yes, but what exactly in this query has a problem being evaluated server side?  There's no reason on a RDMS this wouldn't execute server side.

Comment: I don't know the answer.  I asked almost the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213529/simplest-group-by-fails-in-ef-3-x-with-client-side-groupby-is-not-supported.  It would be great if they would document exactly what works and what doesn't.